# How to convert Word Doc with tables to csv and output as JSON

Tags: python, pandas, csv, ms-word, extract

I have the following code to extract tables from a word doc and create a list of csv files from the tables:

```
from docx import Document
import pandas as pd
import csv 
import json
import time
document = Document('pathtoFile')

tables = []
for table in document.tables:
    df = [['' for i in range(len(table.columns))] for j in range(len(table.rows))]
    for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        for j, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            if cell.text:
                df[i][j] = cell.text
    tables.append(pd.DataFrame(df))

    for nr, i in enumerate(tables):
        i.to_csv("table_" + str(nr) + ".csv")
```

I also have the following script to take a csv file and extract it to JSON:

```
import csv 
import json
import time

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonArray = []
      
    #read csv file
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as csvf: 
        #load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 

        #convert each csv row into python dict
        for row in csvReader: 
            #add this python dict to json array
            jsonArray.append(row)
  
    #convert python jsonArray to JSON String and write to file
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)
          
csvFilePath = r'pathtoFile'
jsonFilePath = r'pathtoFile'

start = time.perf_counter()
csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
finish = time.perf_counter()

print(f"Conversion completed successfully in {finish - start:0.4f} seconds")
```

The main issue is combining the two and figuring out how to go about taking the word document with the tables, extracting them to csv's, then taking the csv and converting to JSON. I may be overcomplicating this but open to suggestions.